# OOP menu system

Tags: c++, qt, oop, menu, composite

I am trying to make a menu system (with submenus) using QGraphics from Qt4.8. 
The Composite Pattern sounds like a good solution but I got stuck.

This is the UML diagram:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/JgWpQ.png

The objects are structured like a tree.

```
      +-------------+
      |Root         |+---------------------+
      +-------------+|                     |
         +           |                     |
         |           |                     |
         |           |                     |
         |           v                     v
+-------<++         +----------+    +----------------+
|Leaf1    |    +---+|MenuNode1 |    | MenuNode2      |+--------+
+---------+    |    +----------+    +----------------+         |
               |            +                  +               |
               |            |                  |               |
               v            v                  v               v
       +---------+ +-----------+     +-------------+       +-------------+
       |Leaf2    | |Leaf3      |     | MenuNode4   |       |Leaf5        |
       +---------+ +-----------+     +-------+-----+       +-------------+
                                     +       |
                                     |       |
                                     |       v
                         +---------+ |  +------------+
                         |         <-+  |            |
                         +---------+    +------------+
```

The first problem is that Qt paints the hole structure, but I want to show only the children of the current node. So I tried to solve this by making all the AbstractMenuItems not visibile and

```
void MenuNode::paint( QPainter *painter, ....) {
    if( this->parentWidget() == AbstractMenuItem::currentPosition) { //show only the direct children
         for(int i = 0; i<3; i++) {//show only 3 elements at a time
              child->at(i)->setVisibile(true);
              child->at(i)->setFocus( i == 1 );
          }  

    } else { //paint as a child
       painter->drawText("Child MenuNode");
    }
}
```

I think my ideea isn't too OO. Any tips for making it better?

Answer (score 0):

First off, I presume you don't want your menu items to be Qt widgets.

Next, to encapsulate the graphic objects you can use [QGraphicsScene](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsscene.html) as a programmable "field" and [QGraphicsItem](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html) for all the menu items you would like to program. It takes more questions/answers to specify more detailed implementation, though. I believe these classes were available in Qt 4.8 as well. You will get advantages of OpenGL-based programming with that easily as well.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! Which class do you think should manage drawing? The scene should go through the structure and pick the items or I should add the hole structure to the scene and every item should decide if and what to draw?

Comment: Well, QGraphicsItem has own looks and your code moves it around the scene. You can add different kind of items and even widgets to the scene. As an alternative I would use QGrapicsProxyWidget and http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsscene.html#addWidget to produce it. See, your question is short and one cannot guess everything you possibly need for implementation.